# Rename all files in directory using PHP and creation date

Tags: php, directory, rename, synology

i have a problem/challenge on my Synology NAS. I have a IPcam connected which takes pictures with file names like:
00A8F700CB18()_1_20140107000224_3674.jpg

Now i would like to rename all those files to something like:
Tue 07-01-2014_11-17-26.jpg (containing date & time)
**And here's the kicker:** I've seen (PHP) scripts using "jhead" or "stat -c", unfortunately those are **not** an option on the Synology!
I cooked something up which works when i use a single file, now i would like to run this script on all the files in a directory!
Please help, i'm not an experienced PHP programmer and i take much joy in the explanation lines in the scrips, gives me and anybody who is whatching this post a learning curve ;)

The script u could use on a single file is something like this:

```
<?php
$stat = stat('/volume1/Ipcam/_Test/00A8F700CB18()_1_20140107000223_3673.jpg');
$motdate = ($stat['ctime']);
$newname =  (gmdate("D d-m-Y_H-i-s", $motdate));
rename("/volume1/Ipcam/_Test/00A8F700CB18()_1_20140107000223_3673.jpg" . "/volume1/Ipcam/_Test/" . $newname . ".jpg");
?>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Google: PHP loop through files in directory. You've already done the actual hard part.

Comment: A.... `DirectoryIterator`?

Answer (score 1):

Read into [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) or [readdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) php functions.

They read a bunch of files in a specified directory and returns an array of file names.

You can then loop through these files and apply the above code to each file.

The examples on php.net are pretty easy to use and modify :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this modification of your code

```
<?php
$dir    = '/volume1/Ipcam/_Test/';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
$stat = stat($file);
$motdate = ($stat['ctime']);
$newname =  (gmdate("D d-m-Y_H-i-s", $motdate));
rename($file, $dir . $newname . ".jpg");
}
?>
```